# How to query a subset of entities with azure storage sdk for node

Tags: odata, azure-storage

I'm trying to query a subset of entities from a storage table on azure.

Here's the documentation I am referring to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/how-to-use-nodejs

Here's my code:

```
    const copyTableName = "LogEventsBackup";
        const partitionKey = "hometasks";
        
        const  const credential = new AzureNamedKeyCredential(connectionObject.AccountName, connectionObject.AccountKey);
        const tableName = "LogEvents";
          
        const serviceClient = new TableClient(
            `https://${connectionObject.AccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
            tableName,
            credential = new TableClient(
            `https://${connectionObject.AccountName}.table.core.windows.net`,
            copyTableName,
            credential
        );          
        
        const entitiesIter = serviceClient.listEntities({
            queryOptions: {                
                filter: odata`PartitionKey eq ${partitionKey}` 
            }
        });
```

I have also installed odata-server:

import * as odata from 'odata-server';

When I run the code, I get this error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
at $data.ODataServer

I also tried removing the odata from the query like so:

```
const entitiesIter = serviceClient.listEntities({
            queryOptions: {                
                filter: `PartitionKey eq ${partitionKey}` 
            }
        });
```

I get this error instead:

The requested operation is not implemented on…db7e4000000\nTime:2022-11-21T10:07:13.3143177Z

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `serviceClient` in your code?

Comment: Sorry, updated my question to show the `serviceClient`

Comment: Thanks. Your `serviceClient` looks odd especially the credential part. Shouldn't you be using `credential` variable there?